# Ebean: weird results

Tags: java, database, playframework-2.0, ebean

this is my Topic's data members:

```
public class Topic extends Model {  
@Id  
protected long id;  
public String title;  
public String content;  
@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn(name = "forumId")  
public Forum forum;  // this is a reference to the topic's forum.
```

**forum attribute saved in postgresql as bigint (the id of the Forum class)**

this is my Finder for Topic:

```
public static Finder<Long,Topic> find = new Finder<Long,Topic>(Long.class, Topic.class);
```

now, I'm trying the simplest thing **using Finder**. retrieve Topics by forum id.
I tried many variations, this is one of them:

```
public static List<Topic> getTopicsByForum(long id) {
    Forum forum = Forum.getById(id);
    return find.where().gt("forumId", forum).findList();
}
```

I get wrong results. I must do something wrong but don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ebean, you can access properties directly, so try this:

```
public static List<Topic> getTopicsByForum(Long forumId) {
    return find.where().eq("forum.id", forumId).findList();
}
```

Comment: ok, it works. but I needed to change from "forumId.id" to "forum.id" as the attribute name.

Comment: ah, yep, sorry; it must be the property name (and not the column name).